# I'm currently using custom certificates for RKE/Rancher, how do I renew custom certificates?

Tags: certificate, rancher, rke

Does renewing RKE custom certificates signed by private CA follows the same process as renewing certificates generated by RKE (e.g. rke cert-rotate)?

Answer (score 0):

I think so, because they write about **keeping the same CA** in documentation when rotating the cert, here is the procedure:

1. In the upper left corner, click ☰ > Cluster Management.
2. On the Clusters page, go to the cluster you want to rotate certificates for and click ⋮ > Rotate Certificates.
3. Select which certificates that you want to rotate:
   Rotate all Service certificates (**keep the same CA**)
   or Rotate an individual service and choose one of the services
4. Click Save.

If you want to rotate RKE certs, the cluster should be "local".

[Read more in the Source - Rancher's Documentation](https://docs.ranchermanager.rancher.io/how-to-guides/advanced-user-guides/manage-clusters/rotate-certificates)